# How to calculate differences between two pandas.Timestamp Series in nanoseconds

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have two Series which are pd.Timestamps, and they are extremely close. I'd like to get the elementwise difference between the two Series, but with nanosecond precision.

First Series:

```
0    2021-05-21 00:02:11.349001429
1    2021-05-21 00:02:38.195857153
2    2021-05-21 00:03:25.527530228
3    2021-05-21 00:03:26.653410069
4    2021-05-21 00:03:26.798157366
```

Second Series:

```
0    2021-05-21 00:02:11.348997322
1    2021-05-21 00:02:38.195852267
2    2021-05-21 00:03:25.527526087
3    2021-05-21 00:03:26.653406759
4    2021-05-21 00:03:26.798154350
```

Now if I simply use the `-` operator, I will truncate the nanoseconds difference. It will show something like this:

```
Series1 - Series2
0    00:00:00.000004
1    00:00:00.000004
2    00:00:00.000004
3    00:00:00.000003
4    00:00:00.000003
```

I don't want to lose the nanosecond precision when calculating the differences between Timestamps. I have hacked up a solution that involves doing a for loop over each row, and calculating the scalar difference in pd.Timedelta, then getting the microseconds and nanoseconds out of that. Like this (for the first element):

```
single_diff = Series1[0] - Series2[0]
single_diff.microseconds * 1000 + single_diff.nanoseconds
4107
```

Is there a neater vectorized way to do this, instead of a for loop?

Comment: You can convert the datetime series to integer (`.astype(int)`) before doing the subtraction; that will give you nanoseconds directly.

Comment: Wonderful, that works! Based on some other answer, I tried converting to numpy uint64 instead, but that also truncated the nanoseconds. But `astype(int)` does not have such a problem. Thank you. If you add it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I have to revise my comment; it's actually not necessary to do the conversion beforehand, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't lose precision if you work with timedelta as shown. The internal representation is always nanoseconds. After calculating the timedelta, you can convert to integer to obtain the difference in nanoseconds. Ex:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s1 = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(["2021-05-21 00:02:11.349001429",
                     "2021-05-21 00:02:38.195857153",
                     "2021-05-21 00:03:25.527530228",
                     "2021-05-21 00:03:26.653410069",
                     "2021-05-21 00:03:26.798157366"]))

s2 = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(["2021-05-21 00:02:11.348997322",
                     "2021-05-21 00:02:38.195852267",
                     "2021-05-21 00:03:25.527526087",
                     "2021-05-21 00:03:26.653406759",
                     "2021-05-21 00:03:26.798154350"]))

delta = (s1-s2).astype(np.int64)

delta
0    4107
1    4886
2    4141
3    3310
4    3016
dtype: int64
```

Note: I'm using numpy's int64 type here since on some systems, the built-in `int` will result in 32-bit integers, i.e. the conversion fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the nanosecond without `numpy`, like this

```py
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series(
    pd.to_datetime(
        [
            "2021-05-21 00:02:11.349001429",
            "2021-05-21 00:02:38.195857153",
            "2021-05-21 00:03:25.527530228",
            "2021-05-21 00:03:26.653410069",
            "2021-05-21 00:03:26.798157366",
        ]
    )
)

s2 = pd.Series(
    pd.to_datetime(
        [
            "2021-05-21 00:02:11.348997322",
            "2021-05-21 00:02:38.195852267",
            "2021-05-21 00:03:25.527526087",
            "2021-05-21 00:03:26.653406759",
            "2021-05-21 00:03:26.798154350",
        ]
    )
)

# before pandas 1.5.0
(s1 - s2 ).apply(lambda x: x.delta)
# 0    4107
# 1    4886
# 2    4141
# 3    3310
# 4    3016
# dtype: int64

# since pandas 1.5.0
(S1 - S2).apply(lambda x: x.value)
# 0    4107
# 1    4886
# 2    4141
# 3    3310
# 4    3016
# dtype: int64
```